# matplotlib: displaying certain labels in different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot certain values, and I need to display certain xlabels in different color than the rest. I am able to set the color of all labels using  "plt.xticks(color = 'r')", but I need certain labels to be in different color than red. Is there any way I can do that? 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the xlabels with `ax.xaxis.get_xticklabels()` and then access individual color values with `tick.set_color('r')`.

For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum(), c='k')

colors = ['r','b']

for n, tl in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    tl.set_color(colors[n%2])
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, such a quick response. :) Thank you so much, it worked like a charm!!

Comment: Okay, it works. but it skips sometimes. I am unable to understand. :(  I try the same code on two different datasets and sometimes it changes the color of the labels and sometimes not. Any idea?

Comment: Could edit your post with an example replicating the behavior? Maybe you are working with the state-machine interface (`plt.plot()` etc) and dont have the right axes while working on it. You can get the active axes with `ax = plt.gca()`. Its guessing without any sample code.

Comment: Oh well... yes, I was using plt. to set axis, changing to ax.set_ fixed the issue. Thanks. :)